# Alternate structure for a sequence of If statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conventions

I'm programming a poker program in JavaScript. I have a Hand class that has the properties "cards", "value" and "valueCards". The value property is an integer that corresponds to a hand type, and the valueCards is the array of five cards that also corresponds to the hand type. For example, if my original seven cards(contained in the cards property) contains a flush, this.value will flip to 6, and this.valueCards will equal only the five cards that equal the highest flush.

I have one method for each hand type, and ALL of them change the value and valueCards if that hand type is detected. I have an accessor method for value called getValue, so when I went to make a method to run all the tests on a hand and keep the highest one, it came out looking like this:

```
POKER.Hand.prototype.getTrueValue = function () {
    this.testStraightFlush();
    if(this.value == POKER.HAND_TYPE.STRAIGHT_FLUSH){ return; }

    this.testQuads();
    if(this.value == POKER.HAND_TYPE.QUADS){ return; }

    this.testFullHouse();
    if(this.value == POKER.HAND_TYPE.FULL_HOUSE){ return; }

    this.testFlush();
    if(this.value == POKER.HAND_TYPE.FLUSH){ return; }

    this.testStraight();
    if(this.value == POKER.HAND_TYPE.STRAIGHT){ return; }

    this.testTrips();
    if(this.value == POKER.HAND_TYPE.TRIPS){ return; }

    this.testTwoPair();
    if(this.value == POKER.HAND_TYPE.TWO_PAIR){ return; }

    this.testPair();
    if(this.value == POKER.HAND_TYPE.PAIR){ return; }

    this.getHighCards();
};
```

I mean, the method works fine. It just bothers me, like maybe I should be doing it a different way. Does this go against convention?

Comment: You want to use the [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)-statement

Comment: But what would be the control variable in the switch statement?

Comment: are your functions `testStraightFlush`, `testQuads` etc. very different by their contents?

Comment: Testing for each hand separately doesn't make much sense. Simply test for number of same ranks, then you have covered everything except straight and straight flush. If there are no same ranks you can test for straight and then (or simultaneously) for straight flush.

Comment: testStraightFlush and testQuads are different. testStraightFlush first tests for flush, gets the suit of those cards, then grabs all the cards of that suit in case there are more than five. Then, if the rank of the first card minus the rank of the fifth card equals 4, it's a straight flush. Quads is a similar mechanism.


I tried testing for the number of the same ranks. It got really messy and I gave up on it. Plus, I figured that hands are a lot easier to compare the way I did it. Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your this.test* functions to return true if the "hand" is found, or return false if not - then you could do something as ugly, yet somehow satisfying, as

```
POKER.Hand.prototype.getTrueValue = function () {
    this.testStraightFlush() ||
    this.testQuads() ||
    this.testFullHouse() ||
    this.testFlush() ||
    this.testStraight() ||
    this.testTrips() ||
    this.testTwoPair() ||
    this.testPair() ||
    this.getHighCards();
};
```

**or**

change your this.test* functions to check only if this.found is false, and set this.found = true if a hand is found, so you'd simply

```
POKER.Hand.prototype.getTrueValue = function () {
    this.found = false;
    this.testStraightFlush();
    this.testQuads();
    this.testFullHouse();
    this.testFlush();
    this.testStraight();
    this.testTrips();
    this.testTwoPair();
    this.testPair();
    this.getHighCards();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but I would redesign your functions :

Each method should return the prop itself :

```
function testFlush ()
 {
   if (...) return POKER.HAND_TYPE.FLUSH;
    return null;
 }


function testStraightFlush()
 {
   if (...) return POKER.HAND_TYPE.StraightFlush;
    return null;
 }
```

This way , you'll be able to get both value and check for truness.

```
POKER.Hand.prototype.getValue= function () 
 {
  return this.testFlush () || testStraightFlush()
 };
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem with that is that my testPair and testTrips methods are such that they verify that they are pairs not trips or quads, and trips, not quads, so that those cards be returned for use in the testFullHouse method. Maybe I should change that to reduce coupling though.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, you could redesign the tests like this:

```
POKER.Hand.prototype.getTrueValue = function () {
    var tests = [
        [ "testStraightFlush", POKER.HAND_TYPE.STRAIGHT_FLUSH ],
        [ "testQuads"        , POKER.HAND_TYPE.QUADS ],
        [ "testFullHouse"    , POKER.HAND_TYPE.FULL_HOUSE ],
        ... etc...
    ];
    for (var test in tests) {
        var fun = this[tests[test][0]];
        var val = tests[test][1];
        fun();
        if (this.value == val) {
            return;
        }
    }
    this.getHighCards();
};
```

Or the functions might simply return a boolean, so you could have a simpler tests array

```
    var tests = [
        "testStraightFlush",
        "testQuads"        ,
        "testFullHouse"    ,
        ... etc...
    ];
```